# What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy, bignum

Is there a bignum built into JavaScript or browsers?

The alternate is loading an external library like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="the_bignum_library.js"></script>
```

but that seems slow and may trigger a security warning.

I've considered basing my own off of http://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger or http://www.mainebrook.com/john/fun/euler.html. Alternately, is the solution to call into a  Java bignum library such as apfloat?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, first you ask for a bignum library, then you provide two on your own? :)

Comment: When I said "exact-rational-arithmetic", I meant "can exactly represent numbers like 1/7". The two libraries I mentioned, as far as I can tell, can't do that -- they can only handle integers.

Comment: There is a [BigRational.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigRational.js) library for exact rational arithmetic.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Thank you, that project (started in 2013) looks like exactly what I was looking for in 2010. Perhaps I should have started such a project myself back then, rather than assuming that surely someone else has already started such a project?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Update(2019-08-19): [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Description) is now part of Firefox and Chrome; you no longer need a library:

```js
const bigInt1 = 1111111111111111111111111111111n;
const bigInt2 = BigInt("1111111111111111111111111111111")
console.log((bigInt1 + bigInt2)+"")
```

Original answer:

If you need arbitrary-precision decimal numbers, use [Javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum), as it is correct and fast.

Comment: This answer [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371529/this-post-has-been-locked-while-disputes-about-its-content-are-being-resolved).

Comment: Not an enlightening discussion. I'm quite a bit frustrated that it seems "illegal" to give an answer to this question which appears more than legit to me.

Comment: So that is on all firefox versions or starting from a particular one?