# How to deal with big numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal, biginteger, bignum

I'm looking for a Mathematical solution that deals with really (long, big, huge, storms) numbers. I haven't found anything yet, But I don't wanna think that this problem hasn't be solve at this time. I'm looking for an easy Number solution, like Microsoft Excel Precision (30 decimals), or a BigInteger (Java) solution. in Javascript of course.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-numbers for converting, formatting, arithmetics and trigonometric operation with big numbers

Comment: Did you ever find a library that handles floating points correctly? Linked answer is integer-only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While looking for an big integer library for an ElGamal crypto implementation I tested several libraries with the following results:

*I recommend this one:* **Tom Wu's jsbn.js (http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)**

- Comprehensive set of functions and fast

**Leemon Baird's big integer library (http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js)**

- Comprehensive set of functions and pretty fast
- **BUT:** Negative number representation is buggy!

**bignumber.js (https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js)**

- Pretty complete set of functions
- **BUT:** Converting really big numbers from strings into BigNumber objects result in INFINITY

**Scheme arithmetic library for JavaScript (https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum)**

- JS-Implementation of Scheme arithmetic functions
- **BUT:** No function for y= x^e mod n

*I haven't tested this by myself:* **BigNumber (http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber)**

- Functions for high precision claculations
- **BUT:** It's said to be slow due to internal representation of numbers as strings

Comment: Does the "BUT" for bignumber.js still hold true - is there an issue about this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a BigInteger library for JavaScript available here:

- [jsbn.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)

(Note that I haven't used this myself. Try it and see what you think.)

Comment: +1 for *an* answer, but **wow** that script needs refactoring. Completely unnecessary global symbols all over the place, just asking for collisions.

Comment: @TJ I think that one's a more-or-less direct translation of the Java BigDecimal class ... it's been around *forever*

Comment: Thanks, it would be great, if it just was a little more easy to understand and extend from.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Silent Matt's [library](http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/) for Big Integers. It does not handle decimals.

Comment: Sorry, but I'was looking for one that manage specially that kind of numbers. :)