# Create Long variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, types, range, long-integer

I need to create a Long variable using JavaScript, like you can do normally in Java by executing this code:

```
long n = 3;
```

My problem is that I need "n" to be very very big, exceeding the range of an integer, because I'm doing big number calculus. Do you know any way to create that? The "var" type of data is long enough for this?

Comment: Please ***read*** the helpful tag pop-ups before you go slapping them on a question!

Comment: JavaScript numbers are 64bit. If you exceed this range (and still need exact results), you will have to use a big-number lib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with big numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you asking if it is long enough? Have you not tried it yet?

Comment: `var` is not a type. I encourage you to read up on JavaScript numbers before doing this or you will have some very nasty shocks.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger library is an option for you

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that allow integers with arbitrary precision, notably:

- [BigInt](http://leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html)
- [gwt-mat](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-math/)