# large number in html5 data element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the correct number from this data url ?

```
<a href="#" id="number" data-number="106454129446370134989">click me</a>

$(function(){
$('#number').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var number= $(this).data('number');
        alert(number);
            //106454129446370130000
})
```

edit: seems .data() has some strange behaviour. Solved it by adding || around the number and stripping it later.

edit2: problem was with jquery 1.7 branch. 1.9 works :-)

Comment: Which browser? Works here using chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/GQ83Y/  FYI, depending what you are attempting to do, you shouldn't convert it to number, keep it as string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @A.Wolff It's not converted to a number anywhere in the code above…

Comment: @feeela ya, that's why i told code should work

Comment: @feeela Maybe `$().data` auto-converts the string to a number, in some browser or version of jQuery? I agree that I couldn't reproduce that behavior, but if that is what's happening, the OP could get around this by adding a non-numeric character to the start or end of the value, and then stripping it after retrieval.

Comment: @apsillers ya, seems fair but then that means .data() behaviour differs from browser to browser as .data() doesn't convert string to number in chrome, as i can test it

Comment: @Johan, that doesnt work since the first string I get is allready different. Im dont receive the correct number so I cant do anything with it :-)

Comment: chrome,latest. Solved it by adding |123456....0| and stripping it later :-) Thx for the suggestion !!

Comment: @user1416256 try using: `$(this).attr('data-number');`  should fix string beeing converted

Comment: @A.Wolff, thx ! problem btw was with jquery 1.7 branch.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't notice that the numbers differed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GQ83Y/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$(this).attr('data-number')
```

Bcoz

```
$(this).data('number')
```

is returning number not string