# Javascript calculate with number over Number.MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript, infinity

i'm writing a small script which calculates very big numbers:

```
for (var i = 1; i<=256; i++) {
    var add = Math.pow(102, i);
    output += add;
    console.log(add);
}
```

the value `add` reaches Infinity in the 153th loop iteration. now the value in `Math.pow` can change and i need the correct output (not infinity). have anybody a trick or sth that could help me? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4288821/251311

Comment: @zerkms I swear I saw the java tag instead of the javascript one. My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @RaulRene If that question answers yours, you can close/delete this one.