# javascript - How to find remainder of a really big integer

Tags: javascript

I find out the *n* th number of the fibonacci sequence by doing this:

```
function add(a, b) {
while (a.length < b.length) a.unshift(0);
while (a.length > b.length) b.unshift(0);
var carry = 0, sum = []
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var s = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
    if (s >= 10) {
        s = s - 10;
        carry = 1;
    } else {
        carry = 0;
    }
    sum.unshift(s);
}
if (carry)
    sum.unshift(carry);
return sum;
}
function fib(n) {
var f1 = [0];
var f2 = [1];

while (n--) {
    var f3 = add(f1, f2)
    f1 = f2;
    f2 = f3;
}
return f1.join("");
}
```

Say, I want to find the remainder when the 1995th fibonacci number is divided by 8. Doing this,

```
fib(1995) % 8
```

returns, however, `NaN`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qe7a/) with output to `console.log`.

So how do I find the remainder of the 1995th fibonacci number divided by 8?

Comment: The divided sign is `/` and not `%`.

Comment: @Jurik I want to find the remainder not the value

Comment: Okay - it's not possible because `Infinity` is the result of `fib(1995) / 8`

Comment: It seems that you exceed the maximum int size in Javascript. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript and try out a big number library.

Comment: If it's just about calculating fibonacci number module some number just take modulo when you do calculations, i.e f(n) % m = (f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)) % m, this way you don't overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have described there is a very particular application of number theory known as the [Pisano period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period):

> In number theory, the nth Pisano period, written π(n), is the period with which the sequence of Fibonacci numbers, modulo n repeats. For example, the Fibonacci numbers modulo 3 are 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, etc., with the first eight numbers repeating, so π(3) = 8.

The Pisano period for n = 8 is 12, so you're looking for the `(1995 % 12)`'th element of the repeating sequence, so:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 0 5 5 2 7 1
      ^
```

#### Update

As mentioned in the comments, at every pair addition you can apply the modulo to keep the numbers manageable:

```
function fib(n, mod)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n <= 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    var current = 1,
    tmp,
    prev = 1;

    while (n > 2) {
        tmp = current;

        current = (current + prev) % mod;
        prev = tmp;

        --n;
    }

    return current;
}

fib(1995, 8); // 2
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with Javascript, but good effort there.

Comment: Without Pisano you can argue: 
The remainder of dividing fn by 8 is equal to: 
the remainder of dividing the sum of the remainders of fn-1 and fn-2
This is exactly what Aleksandr Nikiforov commented.

Comment: @chris97ong I've added an example of continuous application of modulo to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem when trying to validate IBAN numbers (European bank account standard). It makes use of a control number to avoid transactions to mistyped accounts (with a modulo 97 result which always should be 1).

I've found a gist ([IBAN javascript validator gist](https://gist.github.com/krypton/5540925)), which is also capable of doing what you need. This is the useful part (**note: the divident parameter must be a STRING**):

```
modulo = function (divident, divisor) {
    var cDivident = '';
    var cRest = '';

    for (var i in divident ) {
         var cChar = divident[i];
         var cOperator = cRest + '' + cDivident + '' + cChar;

         if ( cOperator < parseInt(divisor) ) {
             cDivident += '' + cChar;
         } else {
             cRest = cOperator % divisor;
             if ( cRest == 0 ) {
                cRest = '';
             }
             cDivident = '';
        }

    }
    cRest += '' + cDivident;
    if (cRest == '') {
        cRest = 0;
    }
    return cRest;
};
```

Basically, it chops the big number into smaller amounts which can be handled by javascript.
Here's a working fiddle:

[jsFiddle example of modulo with big integers in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/u3YkU/4/)

Comment: Could you post a fiddle? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cache = {};
var result = 0;
function fib_mod(number, mod) {
    if( cache[number] ) return cache[number];

    if( number < 3 ) result = 1 % mod; // 1st is 1, 2nd is 1 too
    else result = (fib_mod(number-2, mod) + fib_mod(number-1, mod)) % mod;

    cache[number] = result;

    return result;
}

fib_mod(1995,8); // output is 2
```

JsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/y5B7q/