# getting NaN, not increment the attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nan

`alert($(this).attr("data-itemindex"));` is giving me **'999999999999999003'**
and `alert(dataValue);` is giving 'NaN'

but why?

I am expecting **'999999999999999004'**

```
alert($(this).attr("data-itemindex"));
var dataValue = Number($(this).attr("data-itemindex")) + 1;
alert(dataValue);
```

Comment: use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` instead of `Number`

Comment: @enyce12 actually my number is too big

Comment: @techouse parsiInt and parseFloat not helping me, still i am getting `NaN`

Comment: I see. The number is too large...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working

```
var dataValue="'999999999999"+("000"+(parseInt($(this).attr("data-itemindex").slice( -3 ),10) + 1).toString()).slice(-3)+"'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your number is too big. The maximum possible number is:

```
9 007 199 254 740 992
```

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t).

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to try this:

https://github.com/rauschma/strint

example of use:

```
var strint = require("./strint");
strint.add("9007199254740992", "1")
//'9007199254740993'
```