# Why isn't value obtained after Masking accurate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hex

I was trying to extract last 32 bits from a Hex number in Javascript.

```
var hex = 0x6C469F301DBBC30;
var last32bit = (hex & 0xFFFFFFFF).toString(16);
log(last32bit); //gives 1dbbc40
```

The result is `1DBBC40`. Shouldn't this supposed to be `1DBBC30` ?
Also how do I preserve the `0` before `1DBBC40`?

Comment: You could try `("00000000"+last32bit).slice(-8)` to preserve

Comment: Thanks. That's a rough workaround I guess. But it'll serve my purpose. The filter is still inaccurate though.

Comment: That number is too big for a 64-bit mantissa.

Comment: `0x6C469F301DBBC30 == 0x6C469F301DBBC40  // true`

Comment: Converting them to integers I get

487631152092003376 != 487631152092003392

Comment: `487631152092003376 == 487631152092003392  // true`

Comment: Converting them *how*?  JavaScript does not represent numbers as integers.

Comment: If you've got the hex representation of the number, then you can extract the last 32 bits by working on that string representation of the value.

Comment: Well I did an online conversion of the numbers. I guess this cannot be handled accurately enough in JS.

String method works accurately. I was just trying to do this mathematically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ECMA standard](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) says:

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 2<sup>64</sup>−2<sup>53</sup>+3)
>   values

Your number is too large to be represented exactly by a Number. You should look for a big number library if you wish to accurately represent large numbers. Perhaps [one of these libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4288821/2101267) would meet your needs.

Comment: @SamikSengupta not with native JavaScript numeric facilities.