# Simple formula in Javascript is infinity

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I've following formula in Wolfram:

*log base 10 of (10^-18x)*

[WolframLink](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+base+10+of+%2810%5E-18x%29+for+x%3D10%5E33) (with x example)

First of all Log Function:

```
function getLog(y) {
    return Math.log(y)/Math.log(10);
}
```

Now I'm trying to get my value:

```
var x = Math.pow(10,33);
var faktor = getLog(Math.pow(10,-(18*x)));
console.log(faktor);
```

console gives -Infinity

What is wrong about my code? Thanks for help.

Comment: So is there even a possibility to calculate this with Javascript?

Comment: Gah I deleted my comment! Original comment was [you are overflowing javascript's maximum int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Comment: Yes, I saw it. So is there a chance to get a workaround or do I need Ajax Requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations are causing floating point [underflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow). A floating point number is roughly represented as 0.<mantissa> × 2<sup><exponent></sup>, so that the distribution of log(|x|) for representable values x is uniformly dense. Both the mantissa and exponent have a certain number of bits allocated for them. The exponent of the representation can only become so small, and if you try to make it smaller than the minimum, the representation is forced to round to 0.

You can instead perform your computations in logspace using [these identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities). A few of these are listed here.

- log(x × y) = log(x) + log(y)
- log(x / y) = log(x) - log(y)
- log(x<sup>y</sup>) = y × log(x)

Comment: So my formula would become `var faktor = (-18*x)*getLog(10);`, which means I don't need log even more?

Comment: @wernersbacher You are computing `var faktor = getLog(Math.pow(10,-(18*x)));`.  That's log10(exp10(-18x)) = -18x. So you can simply compute `var faktor = -18 * x;` instead.

Comment: When x is 10^33, y should be 15 (Take a look on my wolfram link), but this is obviously another result. I think i made a huge mistake, its not 10^(-18*x), it's 10^(-18)*x what is completely different. i'm investigating.

Comment: well, now vanilla javascript can handle it. still thank you very much, your answer helped me while searching my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the maximum integer allowed in JavaScript by quite a bit.

[Max int in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

[Wolfram proof because why not](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9007199254740992+%3C+%2810%5E33%29)

You are going to need a big number extension of JavaScript, which SO has many posts about. [See here for what appears to be unlimited integer math](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber)

More posts like this can be chased starting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: So I have x to set like this: `var x = new BigNumber(Math.pow(10,33));` and calculate like before?

Comment: You have to use the library and ***only*** that library. If you try to do x * 4 you will get infinity. JavaScript cannot handle that, but that BigNumber extension and set of functions can.

Comment: The problem is, that there is no logarithm function in bignumber.js and I can't find a library with it. :(

Comment: @AdmiralAdama The problem is underflow, not overflow. `-18*Math.pow(10,33)` computes just fine in Javascript, because it is using a floating point representation: `-1.8000000000000002e+34`

Answer (score 0):

### Code

Values in practice:

```
var x = Math.pow(10,33);           // x = 1.0000000000000001e+33
var exponent = -18*x;              // exponent = -1.8000000000000002e+34
var deci = Math.pow(10, exponent); // deci = 0
var logged = Math.log(deci);       // logged = NaN (-Infinity)
var result = logged/Math.log(10);  // result = NaN (-Infinity)
```

The problem is that floating point values can have decimal exponents in the range -308 to +308 (approximately, it's really all in binary), and your exponent is approximately 18,000,000,000,000,002,000,000,000,000,000,000.

### Maths

Maths gives us log(x<sup>y</sup>) = y.log(x). And that log<sub>b</sub>(b) = 1. Thus,

log<sub>10</sub>(10<sup>-18x</sup>) = -18x.log(10) = -18x.

So the maths lesson is that "logging X (base b)" and "raising b to the power of X" are **inverse operations**.