# Big JavaScript ints won't cast to String without rounding

Tags: javascript, html, bigint

I am trying to pass a big int to a function from an onclick event in HTML. The ints are always very long, and I cannot seem to pass it to my function without rounding. I have tried some bigInt libraries to the same end, though I would much rather prefer simple string casting.

My js function:

```
    function initBuy(id){
      console.log(id.toString());
    }
```

and my HTML event:

```
<dt></dt><dd><a id="buy" onclick="initBuy(String(' + all_data[index].listing_id + '))" class="btn btn-success">Buy This Item</a></dd>
```

An example of a passed int:

```
13934317650292905813
```

and the result of clicking the button:

```
"13934317650292906000"
```

The passed int looks fine when I write it to an elements' text. When I pass it to a function, however, it's rounding it.

Comment: Is that line with the HTML part of some server-side code? What is `all_data`?

Comment: I just added the String() in the HTML because nothing else was working, and it didn't either. all_data is just a json array.

Comment: There's no reason for `.listing_id` to be a number in the first place if it's just an ID. Represent it as a string in your JSON and in the `all_data` object. Don't use `String()`.

Comment: I know the number is too big for JavaScript. However, I'm not asking how to expand JavaScripts max precision. If I set all_data[index].listing_id to an elements text, it works. I want to know why I can't convert it to a String.

Comment: nnnnnn: I don't have control over the json

Comment: If you don't have control over the source JSON and it has that value as a number then by the time you try to convert the property to a string it is too late because JavaScript is already representing the value as a JS number and the precision has been lost. You'd need to manipulate the JSON _before parsing it_ to change the numeric value to a string. (How complicated is the source JSON? You might be able to do a regex replace to add quotation marks around the numbers before parsing it.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: but.. the OP clearly states he already *has* a string: `The passed int looks fine when I write it to an elements' text. When I pass it to a function, however, it's rounding it.` and in comment: `If I set all_data[index].listing_id to an elements text, it works.`.. If the "int" wasn't a string the OP *could not* write it successfully to the "elements' text".. Thus my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in your (ambiguous) question:

> 'The passed int looks fine when I write it to an elements' text. When I pass it to a function, however, it's rounding it.'

and in your comment:

> If I set `all_data[index].listing_id` to an elements text, it works.

### That means you are already getting the 'integer' as text-string in JSON.

Nothing in your current question converts the string to a number (I tested it).
As soon as the string would be converted to a number it would overflow IEEE 754's max accuracy of 2^53=9007199254740992.

Note that: `initBuy(String(' + all_data[index].listing_id + '))`
will return the string `+ all_data[index].listing_id +` (as it should).

Passing the string `'13934317650292905813'` to your `initBuy` function also returns string `'13934317650292905813'` (as it should).

In other words, I can not reproduce your problem using the code you have supplied.

I assume you have simplified your `initBuy` function for this question (you'd have to post the original one for further examination, preferably together with an excerpt of a relevant part of the *raw* JSON string).

I assume **you** might accidentally convert the string to a number (probably using a `+`) inside that function!

Answer (score 1):

From the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) the maximum value an integer in Javascript could take is `9007199254740992`

Your number `13934317650292905813` is far bigger than that.

From this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript) you can use [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) to accommodate big integers

Comment: The mere act of passing string `'13934317650292905813'` to a function (as an argument) does not convert it to a (floating point) number; it should still be a string (until the OP (accidentally) converts it).