# Javascript - simple division leads to error

Tags: javascript, math, division

If I use the windows calculator to calculate

`(1.75 + 3/1.75)/2` it yields to =

`1,7321428571428571428571428571429`

If I do the same with javascript it yields to

`1.732142857142857206298458550009`

So at position 22 after the decimal point the result becomes incorrect `...142857...` vs. `...206298...`

```
var a = 1.75;
var res = (a+3/a)/2;
console.log(res.toFixed(30));
```

How can I make my division precise for 31 digits after the decimal comma?

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't do that "per se", since its double variables have a limited precision. You'll need to use an external library to handle operations with big precision numbers, like this one: [Javascript Bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum)