# Datatable datatools export features provide wrong value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable datatool plugin for exporting data from datatable.

I have one value like `9001030110184204` and It is exporting in excel as `9.00103E+15` that means `9001030110184200`

It comes last digit as 0.

How can we solve this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with big numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no relation between above quest. It is based on datatable plugin

Comment: It's related in how javascript handles the big numbers. So it's a duplicated topic. datatables plugin is a javascript plugin that manages the big numbers with javascript, not infuse science.