# Javascript - parsing a hex value

Tags: javascript, decode, bitwise-operators

I am trying to parse a hex value to decode a card

The hex data I receive from the card is `f8b2d501f8ff12e0056281ed55`

First I am converting this to an integer with parseInt()

```
    var parseData = parseInt('f8b2d501f8ff12e0056281ed55', 16);
```

The value recieved is `1.9703930145800871e+31`

When I try to decode this using the bitwise operator in Javascript

```
    var cardNumber = ((parseData & 0xFFFFF) >> 1).toString();
```

I received a `0` value.

What am I doing wrong here, how can I parse the value of such large integer number?

Comment: Your number is so big that it is transformed into a floating point number, and the rightmost digits are lost, i.e. set to 0. But if you are just interested in the rightmost 5 digits you can simply take a substring of your original hex number.

Comment: What does the hex represent,.?  If your saying this is a number, that would equal an 104 bit number so I would imagine it's not.  Do you have the file format for what this card hex data represents.

Comment: Why you edited your question?

Comment: The xx in `f9030xx22` are not valid hexadecimal characters.

Comment: @Bergi, well I answered his question, and then he did some weird edits, as you can see in revisions history. I don't know why.

Comment: @DawidLoranc I already tried to rollback - now flagging for mod attention.

Comment: @Zuif, please do not significantly change your question, if you have a new problem then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it. Also your edited code doesn't make any sense, `parseInt('f903022', 1);` does return NaN not 1.9…e31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

First, notice that `& 0xFFFFF` operation in your code is just equivalent to getting a substring of a string (the last 5 characters).

So, you can just do a substring from the end of your number, and then do the rest:

```js
var data = 'b543e1987aac6762f22ccaadd';
var substring = data.substr(-5);

var parseData = parseInt(substring, 16);
var cardNumber = ((parseData & 0xFFFFF) >> 1).toString();

document.write(cardNumber);
```

The second way is to use any big integer library, which I recommend to you if you do any operations on the large integers.

Comment: @zuif, I changed. You should also edit you question and change `parseInt('f903022', 1);` to `parseInt('f903022', 16);`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number integer is so big you should use any bigNum library for js.

I recommend [BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js), since you are working only with integers and it supports bitwise operations, however you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript) answer for more options.