# Jquery / Javascript - Math with long numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a few numbers form my view:

```
var total      = '100.000.559,99';
var paymentOne = '560';
var paymentTwo = '99.999.999,99';
```

I change my paymentOne, so I want to recount them. I wrap all the numbers in: parseFloat, but my `100.000.559,99` will be `100`. So that wont works..

So my question is, how can I use them for math?

Comment: `100.000.559,99` is not a valid JavaScript number. Use `100000559.99` or search for a library that interprets locale numbers (because it changes depending on the language used)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the conversion to floats with something like that:

```
+total.split(".").join("").replace(",", ".");  // 100000559.99
```

Or with regex:

```
+total.replace(/[.,]/g, function(c) { return c === "," ? "." : "" });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using commas instead of periods, and periods where you don't need them at all.  Try this:

```
var total      = 100000559.99;
var paymentOne = 560;
var paymentTwo = 99999999.99;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before parsing you could do the following

```
var total = '100.000.559,99';
total = total.replace( /\./g, "" ).replace( /,/g, "." );
```

Probably better off wrapping it in a function

```
function convertToFloat( num ) {
    num = num.replace( /\./g, "" ).replace( /,/g, "." );
    return parseFloat( num );
}
```

Comment: Nope, it will return `"100000.559.99"`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot the `g` flag.