# How come I can't add 1 to a large number in javascript

Tags: javascript, biginteger

```
var i = 20040115102010000;

i++;

returns 20040115102010000;
```

Do I have to use a Big Number Library?

[What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)

This number was already in floating point format and I moved the decimal place to the left three times.  Also, notice, it is a date. Would it behoove me to convert this number to a date format first? Will I find it easier to increment in milliseconds in the `Date()` object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/behove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will increase your number by 1. e.g if digits = 12346456783211345;
**digits = (BigInt(digits)) + BigInt(1);**

After using BigInt it will be look like 12346456783211346

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a Date that big in javascript, without making a bigDay library to handle your bignums.

/*

from 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date':

The JavaScript date is measured in milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC.
*/

```
var firstday=new Date(1970,0,1),lastday=new Date(1969,11,31);

firstday.setDate(firstday.getDate()-100000000);

lastday.setDate(lastday.getDate()+100000000);

firstday.toUTCString()+'; timestamp: '+firstday.getTime()+'\n'+
lastday.toUTCString()+'; timestamp: '+lastday.getTime();
```

/*  returned value: (largest and smallest Dates in JS)

Tue, 20 Apr -271821 04:00:00 GMT; timestamp: -8639999985600000

Fri, 12 Sep 275760 04:00:00 GMT; timestamp: 8639999928000000
*/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript now has a bigint type.