# The result of JavaScript calculation with large numbers is inaccurate

Tags: javascript, python, math

[image]

Why is this happening to me?? I multiply the same numbers in python and chrome's JS console but it seems as if JS has forgotten how to calculate.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @ericbn then why is this happening??

Comment: Overflow, my friend, overflow... Python is a bit smarter then JavaScript when it comes to big numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Python integer numbers are long ints](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/).

JavaScript numbers are (double) floating points. [The largest accurate JavaScript integer value is 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t):

9007199254740992

Your number exceeds this value. [If you need to handle integers accurately in JavaScript over the floating point threshold you need to some big number library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript).

Comment: Wow.  That's a terrible failure mode.  JavaScript sucks for numbers.

Comment: @wim: take it up with IEEE, they defined the behavior of floating-point types once precision is lost