# Does parseDouble exist in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point-precision

In JavaScript, I have a number which is 21 digits, and I want to parse it.

Does a parseDouble method exist in JavaScript?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's not possible to natively deal with a 21-digit precision number in JavaScript.

JavaScript only has *one* kind of number: "number", which *is* a [IEEE-754 Double Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) ("double") value. As such, `parseFloat` in JavaScript is the equivalent of a "parse double" in other languages.

However, a number/"double" *only* provides 16 significant digits (decimal) of precision and so reading in a number with 21-digits *will* lose the 5 least significant digits<sup>1</sup>.

For *more* precision (or accuracy) a "big number" library must be used;

- [What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)

<sup>1</sup> Information can be lost when encoding as an IEEE "double", which cannot encode all decimal values exactly, but [that's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)..

Comment: I have to parse a 21 digit number which does not have any decimal places. BigInteger and BigNumber can only parse upto 16 digits with precision. But I have a number larger than that and I need that to be parsed precisely. Pls advise. Suggestions with syntax highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @PriyeshShah You need to start with a *string* and pass this to BigInteger/BigNumber to parse. As soon as you have a *number* value in JavaScript then it's subject to the limits above - that is, it has *already* lost the less significant digits.