# javascript function parking hours

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is the full question

> Write a complete for charging the parking fee for each customer based on the number of  hour parking. 
>   Ask user to enter the total hour using prompt()
>   Calculate the amount of charge that a customer has to pay using the function calcCharge(). 
>   This function receive  the total hour or parking through its parameter. It then calculate and returns the amount of charges to the customer.
>   The formula to calculate the amount of charges to the customer : 
>   In the first hour, the charge is RM 1.00. In the next  hour, the addition charge is RM 0.50 per hour. The maximum charge is RM 10.00.
>   Calculate the total charge of all the customers using function calcTotal(). 
>   Display the amount of charges for a customer.
>   Display total charge of all customer using alert()

and ive tried to do the code but fail.

 i fail to display the total charge of a customer and total charge for all customers.

i hope somebody willing to help me, thanks!

```html
<html>
<head><title>Calculate Parking Hours</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcCharge()
{
 var hour=parseInt(document.fee.hour.value);
 var tot;
 if (hour==1)
  tot=1;
 else if (hour>1 && hour<=20)
  tot=1+0.5*(hour-1);
 else
  tot=10;
 
 
 document.write("The total charge is : RM "+tot);
  
}

function calcTotal()
{
 var totCha;
 totCha=parseInt(totCha);
 totCha+=document.tot.value;
 alert("Total charge all customers"+totCha);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="calcTotal()">
<form name="fee" method="post">
Hour : <input name="hour" type="text"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Total Charge" onclick="calcCharge()">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your logic be `tot=1+0.5*(hour-1);` instead of `tot=1+0.5*hour;`..As for first hour, RM 1.00 is taken..

Comment: [parseDouble method not exist in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278234/does-parsedouble-exist-in-javascript), `var totCha;
 totCha=parseDouble(totCha);` - you try parse _undefined_ it any way **NaN**

Comment: ive corrected the error, but how to calculate the total charge for all customers?

Comment: also see MDN:[Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: @KyraShin Where are you taking input for number of customers?

Comment: methinks you need move your question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: from the form field input

Comment: @KyraShin did you try with my code ? let me know if you  have any difficulies

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yup your code worked thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your question you say `calcCharge()` function receive the total hour or parking through its parameter.The reality is you didn't pass any argument to your function. IF you want it in a right way then  try the below code

**html**

```
<input type="button"onclick="calcCharge(document.getElementById('text1').value)"/>
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
```

**js**

```
function calcCharge(value)
{

var hour=parseInt(value);
 var tot=0;
if (hour==1)
         tot=1;
    else if (hour>1 && hour<=20)
{
        tot=1+(0.5*(hour-1));
}
    else
{
        tot=10;
}


    alert(tot);

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b8s678b1/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Update the following line:**

```
var hour = parseInt(document.getElementByName("hour").value);
```