# How to obtain only the integer part of a long floating precision number with JS?

Tags: javascript, floating-point-precision

I know there's

- `Math.floor`
- `parseInt`

But about this case:

```
Math.floor(1.99999999999999999999999999)
```

returning 2, how could I obtain only its integer part, equals to 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1.99999999999999999999999999` is *not* the actual value of the number. It has a *value of 2* after the literal is parsed because this is 'as best' as JavaScript can represent such a value.

JavaScript numbers are [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) or "[double precision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which allow for 15 to 17 significant [decimal] digits of precision - the literal shown requires 27 significant digits which results in information loss.

Test: `1.99999999999999999999999999 === 2` (which results in true).

Here [is another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278297/2864740) that describes the issue; the finite relative precision is the problem.

Comment: So I should rather use another language? COBOL?

Comment: @diegoaguilar To do.. what? You're using JavaScript for a reason :)

Comment: Numerical analysis app in a Node.js API

Comment: @diegoaguilar There are various libraries available to help with 'big numbers' or 'rationals' or 'fixed precision', etc. However JavaScript's number type is incapable of directly dealing with this situation.