# Javascript += equivalent?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

My code is a simple function that checks which radio button was pressed, and adds the value of that radio button to my `var input = 0;`. However, I know I am doing something wrong as it works but the output is wrong. When one of the `if` statements is true, instead of input(0) now being equal to itself plus the new value of the `getElementById("small").value`, it prints out `010` as opposed to the now `10`.

I know in Java there was a convention similar to `input += getElementById("small").value;` but this doesn't seem to work. So as you can see in my example below, I tried the alternative of `input = input + /*code*/;` but still no luck.

I am new to JavaScript but very familiar with Java. I imagine I'm just using the wrong syntax here but all my Google searches are a bust.

```
function calculate()
{
    var input = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("small").checked) 
    {
        input = input + document.getElementById("small").value;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("medium").checked)
    {
        input = input + document.getElementById("medium").value;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("large").checked)
    {
        input = input + document.getElementById("large").value;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("failed");
    }

    document.getElementById("outar").innerHTML = input;
}
```

Comment: you need to `parseInt(value)` to convert to a integer rather than a text value when grabbing number values from the dom.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to do arithmetic with a string. You need to use `parseInt()` around each of your `document.getElementById("....").value` expressions because the `.value` property is a string.

Example:

```
input += parseInt(document.getElementById("small").value);
```

Comment: ahhhh! this makes so much more sense. I was looking at the return type of .value and was trying to make sense of how to parse it. Are there all types of Parse? parseDouble/Int/Float, etc?

Comment: @SenjuXo just `parseInt` and `parseFloat`; JavaScript doesn't have a (native) `parseDouble`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21278297/2057919

Answer (score 2):

Your value is not a number by default, it's a string. You got to parse it first:

```
input += parseInt(document.getElementById("large").value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional + symbol before string value in order to convert it to number:

```
input += +document.getElementById("large").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `.value` to a number as an integer or a float with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`. `.value` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is dynamically typed language, not static typed like java.
document.getElementById("small").value returns a string which needs to be converted to int with parseInt().

Ho[e that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to this [link-](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp)

The returned value from the value is a string . You have to convert it to int before doing any arithmetic operations.

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, not static typed like java.

**Return Value**:   A String, representing the value of the text field