# MySQL numeric operation oddities - overflow?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this first query on MySQL?

The expected answer for both columns is '718042670591505846'

```
SELECT 5002622390 + (5102 * 140737488355328) new_iid_hard_way,
     CAST(5002622390 + (5102 * POWER(2,47)) AS UNSIGNED) new_iid_WRONG_way
```

It returns:

'718042670591505846', '718042670591505792'

Meanwhile, this query works:

```
SELECT 5002622390 + (5102 * 140737488355328) new_iid_hard_way,
   5002622390 + (5102 * CAST(POWER(2,47) AS UNSIGNED)) new_iid_CORRECT_way
```

It returns :
'718042670591505846', '718042670591505846'

My hunch is that it is a datatype overflow / wrapping issue... but even with Strict mode enabled on MySQL 5.6.15, I don't get any errors.

Interestingly, sqlfiddle gets it wrong in all 4 cases:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1bb6/1

returning 718042670591505800

Is this an overflow issue?  If yes, why isn't MySQL throwing an error when strict mode is enabled?

Comment: From my experience, Mysql prefers to do the wrong thing and return no error when possible.  I wonder if the same issue comes up on other DB's

Comment: I think you get an implicit data type conversion by the expression (5102 * POWER(2,47) to an floating point type and lose precision in the addition before you do the cast. Have a look at `SELECT CAST(5102 * POWER(2, 47) AS UNSIGNED), 5102 * POWER(2, 47);`

Comment: And there's no overflow because there's no column with a defined data type.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442089/difference-between-real-calculation-number-and-the-one-i-calculate-with-javascri/24442144#24442144 It's for Javascript, but I suspect a similar issue is involved here.

Comment: @Barmar It's interesting that different machines get different results. On sqlfiddle with MySQL 5.6.6 (as it said) the cast doesn't make any difference at all, at my Windows 8.1 64-bit computer with MySQL 5.6.16 (no great difference at all) I can reproduce the behavior in the question.

Comment: I think sqlfiddle does its own post-processing of the output. E.g. if you have a `date` column, it displays it as a `datetime`. So it could be using floating point for everything before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Some operations are done in `DECIMAL`, some are done in `DOUBLE`.  This should explain why the numbers differ after about the 16th significant digit.

Here is another way to do it:

```
5002622390 + (5102 << 47)
```

`<<` is binary shift, so it has the same effect as `*POW(2, ...)`

Using DECIMAL gets the right answer of 718042670591505846:

```
SELECT CAST(5002622390 AS DECIMAL) + (5102 * 140737488355328);
SELECT CAST(5002622390 AS DECIMAL) + (5102 << 47)
```