# parseInt changes the integer

Tags: javascript, integer, substring, parseint

I am trying to pull a number (721576481415319**78**), which starts at the 21st character, out of the title of a page like so:

```
parseInt(document.title.substring(21), 10);
```

This returns the string as an integer of 721576481415319**80**. I can't seem to figure out why it is changing the last two numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the full title string?

Comment: @Sebas - Oh I see it now.

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2013/01/parseint.html, interesting articles, `all numbers are floating points in javascript` mind blown!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t) the max value of an integer is 9007199254740992.

I tried your calculation on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint and I can confirm your problem.

It looks like an issue parsing beyond this max value and it is rounding the last 2 figures.

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded the limits of [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), as used by JavaScript. You cannot use that precise number directly in JavaScript. You can use it as a string, but if you need to do arithmetic on it you will need [a bignum library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript).