# Getting more than 17 decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

It's possible to find the repeating part of a decimal by iterating through ever greater sections of the decimal and then checking it with the next chunk.

Ex.(1/28)
0.03571428571428571, 0.03[**571428**]571428

However, there are always rather large repetition lengths.

Ex. (31/89)

0.[**34831460674157303370786516853932584269662921**]34831460674157303370786516853932584269662921....

The problem with using javascript to evaluate a fraction out of 0.[**34831460674157303370786516853932584269662921**]34831460674157303370786516853932584269662921....
is that javascript has a max of 17 decimals. 
How do I get more decimals?

Comment: What @AmitJoki said.

Comment: the answer is you just cant ..

Comment: I think it's [IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)'s fault, and the size of 64 bits. Next gen might use 128 bits floats.

Comment: You can use an [arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) math library to "longhand" calculate with more digits. See for example the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript).

Comment: So you'd have to use a separate math library...

Comment: Yes, @mellamokb is correct (you should turn this comment into an answer), and this applies to about any general-purpose programming language. Arbitrary precision arithmetic must be done in software, because the hardware isn't designed to support it out of the box (IEE 754).

Answer (score 0):

As mention in comments you can't. And tha't why:

> Javascript is not a typed language so it should come as no surprise
>   that there are no specific integer or floating-point types, no short,
>   long, byte, double, or any other type other languages use to define
>   numbers. All numbers in Javascript are 64bit (8 bytes) floating point
>   numbers which yields an effective range of 5e-324 (negative) to
>   1.7976931348623157e+308 (positive).
>
> This reference will cover Javascript numeric literals and objects as
>   well as the default Javascript Operators which manipulate those
>   numbers.

[more..](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference)