# Converting big numbers from string to number

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to convert a big/very long numeric string into a number:

```
+'-000000098765432112345.67898765432100000';
'-000000098765432112345.67898765432100000'*1;
parseFloat('-000000098765432112345.67898765432100000', 10);
```

All these tests will output `-98765432112345.67` instead of the expected `-98765432112345.678987654321`.

Why does it happens?

**NB:** The proposed duplicated solution doesn't answer my question, it just gives a solution to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the standard solution in Javascript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, I want to know why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual cause with big numbers is because of overflow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow.

This answers the similar question 'at what point will overflow occur  in Javascript': [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)