# facing an issue with parseFloat when input is more than 16 digits

Tags: javascript

I am facing weird issued.

`parseFloat(11111111111111111)` converts it to `11111111111111112`.

I noticed that it works fine till `length is 16` but rounds off higher when input `length is > 16.`

I want to retain the original value passed in `parseFloat` after it is executed.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Integers (numbers without a period or exponent notation) are considered accurate up to 15 digits.

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thanks for suggestion, I've got it.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in javascript are represented using 64 bit floating point values (so called `doubles` in other languages).

`doubles` can hold at most 15/16 significant digits (depends on number magnitute). Since range of double is 1.7E+/-308 some numbers can only be aproximated by `double`, in your case 11111111111111111 cannot be represented exactly but is aproximated by 11111111111111112 value. If this sounds strange then remember that 0.3 cannot be represented exactly as double too.

`double` can hold exact integers values in range +/-2^53, when you are operating in this range - you may expect exact values.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a constant, [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)  which is the highest integer that can be exactly represented.

> Safe in this context refers to the ability to represent integers exactly and to correctly compare them. For example, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2 will evaluate to true, which is mathematically incorrect.

The value is 9007199254740991 (2^53 - 1) which makes a maximum of 15 digits safe.

Answer (score 1):

- JavaScript now has [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

> BigInt is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 253 - 1, which is the largest number JavaScript can reliably represent with the Number primitive.
>
> BigInt can be used for arbitrarily large integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the unary `+` operator.
Like this + ("1111111111111111") + 1 = 1111111111111112

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [following blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html), JavaScript only supports 53 bit integers.

if you type in the console 
     `var x = 11111111111111111`
and then type
    `x`
you'll get 
    `11111111111111112`
This has nothing to do with the `parseFloat` method.

There's also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum) about working with big numbers in JavaScript.