# How to do exact calculation when numbers are not in Safe Integer range?

Tags: javascript

[I found that JavaScript performs an exact calculation when numbers are in safe integer range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

```
Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER = -9007199254740991 = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991 = -(Math.pow(2, 53) - 1)
```

Is it possible to do calculation beyond this range without rounding off and losing precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use something like big numbers. These numbers are represented as a string of decimal characters which are then operated by the library.

Check this out: [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum)

Answer (score 1):

According to ECMAScript 6 there is no function to handle the specified operation. Even if we write a function for the same, I think we can't hold the value of the variable, which is to be computed with precision in js.