# javascript toString converts long numbers to Infinity

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Hi All,

Doing something like this

```
alert(999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999);
```

results in this

[image: Javascript Popup 1e+48]

How to i stop converting a number to a string from saying 1e+XX or Infinity?

Comment: I just need to hear the use case for this.

Comment: `1e+48 != ∞` last time I checked.

Comment: @Andrew putting in higher numbers ends up at javascript saying infinity

Comment: @zoidbery the user enters text in a textarea and then shows it on the screen (very similar to this comment feature) and i convert it to a string so i can change < and > to &lt; and &gt; so it displays. If the user enters a long number then the number.toString() converts to 1e+XX

Comment: Don't convert it to a number, keep it as a string.

Comment: It gets sent to the database as a string and stored in a [TEXT] field. But whenever i get it from the database and try to show it it says infinity.

Comment: @Timothy The user enters a string into the textarea, not a number. What number are you talking about?

Comment: If the user does enters only digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only so many digits that will actually be able to maintain precision so when you reach that limit it starts using the e+ notation...

alert(' '+ 12345678901234567890 + ' ')

Will output 12345678901234567000

So for example also if you did

alert(' '+ 999999999999999999 + ' ')

You get  1000000000000000000

GL...

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have provided the  most obvious solution which is to enclose in quotes so that javascript treats it as a string and not a number.

```
alert('999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');
```