# How to convert a String containing Scientific Notation to correct Javascript number format

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, format

I have a String `e.g: "4.874915326E7"`. What is the best way to convert it to a javascript number format? (int or float)? if I try parseInt(), the ***E*** at the end is ignored.

Comment: That's usually referred to a [Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) (sometimes as Scientific E Notation, but whatever...)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

#### Edit:

*This answer seems to be generating some confusion.  The original question was asking how to convert scientific notation in the form of a string to a number (so that it could be used for calculation).  However, a significant number of people finding this answer seem to think it's about converting a number that is being represented by javascript as scientific notation to a more presentable format.  If that is in fact your goal (presentation), then you should be converting the number to a string instead.  Note that this means you will not be able to use it in calculations as easily.*

#### Original Answer:

Pass it as a string to the Number function.

```
Number("4.874915326E7") // returns 48749153.26
Number("4E27") // returns 4e+27
```

#### Converting a Number in Scientific Notation to a String:

This is best answered by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript), but from that question I personally like [the solution that uses `.toLocaleString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978675/854246). Note that that particular solution doesn't work for negative numbers.  For your convenience, here is an example:

```
(4e+27).toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false}) // returns "4000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: Mine not working. `Number("1.7976931348623157e308")`

Comment: @The_ehT It works for me.  `typeof Number("1.7976931348623157e308")` returns "Number" for me when I run that exact code in the console.  running it in console without the `typeof` returns the number "1.7976931348623157e+308".

Comment: @JosephMarikle but I want my number in standard notation not in scientific.

Comment: @The_ehT Ah!  that makes sense.  This question was on how to convert it to a "javascript number format" presumably to allow for working with it and other numbers, performing math against the numeric value.  You want to convert yours to the extended format, which you would need a string for.  Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139452/how-to-convert-big-negative-scientific-notation-number-into-decimal-notation-str?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can convert that way but some digits gets lost if I do like that. For eg. I have a recursive function where last answer coming like 4.12345678e10, if I convert this to standard notation it would result like this 41234567800 where last two digits 00 are not actually 00. So it would be better if there is a way to prevent conversion to scientific notation or any other hack.

Comment: This is pretty dependent on the source of the data.  Is it a javascript source?  Generally, the scientific notation should only ever come into play when you're trying to format it for display.  For instance, if you have a number that results in 4.12345678e10 but is stored as 4.1234567873, it should remain the second option in your variable until you try to convert it to a string to be passed to a server or stored in a DB or whatever else reason.  Where in your application does it get passed as the scientific notation?

Comment: May be running into the issue of javascript's max integer value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: Not work for this number `Number('2.801831040211423e+28')`

Comment: @janwen Once again, `typeof Number('2.801831040211423e+28')` will indicate that it is in fact converting it to a number.  If you're wanting to convert it to something more suitable for presentation, you might consider converting it to a formatted string. [This was linked above and might be useful to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139452/how-to-convert-big-negative-scientific-notation-number-into-decimal-notation-str?lq=1)

Comment: Does'nt work for Number(1234567890*999999999999999).toString()

Comment: @RK_15 Please re-read the question and answer.  That code snippet is unrelated to my response.  It looks like you're trying to convert a large number to a string, but this question and answer is the opposite.  OP was trying to convert a scientific notation string to a number.

Comment: how about 3.8e-7, i get the same output number 3.8e-7

Comment: @sasharomanov Please see my edit.  Getting back `3.8e-7` is expected behavior.  The person originally asking the question was *wanting* a number.  You can't easily add 0.5 to the ***string*** "0.00000038".  Therefore, my assumption is that you might actually be needing to convert your scientific notation to a string for presentation purposes.  For that you can try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: ```parseInt(Number('1e+20') )
100000000000000000000
parseInt(Number('1e+21') )
1
Math.floor(Number('1e+20') )
100000000000000000000
Math.floor(Number('1e+21') )
1e+21```
Works for my use case, trying to get ints from a very large string in scientific notation

Comment: `.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})` saved me :) Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I had a value like this `3.53048874968162e-09` and using `Number.toFixed(20)` worked for me:

```
value = new Number('3.53048874968162e-09')
//[Number: 3.53048874968162e-9]
value.toFixed(20)
//'0.00000000353048874968'
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation *why* it worked and a reference, especially when adding one to an old question (such answers go to the review queue). Note that the question is not about formatting strings representing numbers but about *converting* to a number format (although the confusion is understandable given how the q. is formulated).

Comment: Also, you should not create new Number objects `new Number()` just to perform type conversion, use the `Number()` directly (will return a primitive type)

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this

## Demo

```
Number("4.874915326E7").toPrecision()
```

Comment: `.toPrecision()` isn't needed here, and adds scientific notation if the precision is lower than the supplied string.

Comment: Number("2.2356434336665664e+51").toPrecision()  
this is not working .. please help me to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `+` sign in front of your string to get a number.

```
+"4.874915326E7" // == 48749153.26
```

Comment: Also works for variables, even in strings: `x="1e3"; ":"+(+x)` gives ":1000".

Comment: Doesn't work after `+"1e20"`, e.g. `+"1e21"` returns `1e21`

Answer (score 2):

**Preamble**

While other answers are sufficient and correct, to be able to correctly parse numbers from strings, it is useful to understand how type coercion (conversion in your case) works at least at high level.

**Coercion rules**

There are rules that define how conversion is performed when you invoke utilities like `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number` constructor or `+` unary operator:

`parseInt(<value>, [radix])` function:

- ignores leading whitespaces (`"   24"` -> `24`)
- empty strings return `NaN`
- first non-numeric char finishes parsing (`"  42answer"` -> `42`)
- under above rule, decimal places finish parsing as well

The third rule is exactly why exponent part (`ExponentPart` consists of `ExponentIndicator` and `SignedInteger` as defined in [standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExponentIndicator)) is ignored - as soon as the `e` char is encountered, parsing stops and the function returns the number parsed so far. In fact, it stops earlier - when the decimal point is first encountered (see the last rule).

`parseFloat()` is identical to `parseInt`, except:

- it parses first decimal point
- ignores leading `0` (thus hexadecimal can't be parsed)

As a rule of thumb, you should use `parseInt` when converting to an "integer" and `parseFloat` to "float" (note that they are actually the same type).

`Number()` constructor and unary `+`:

- For boolean -> `true` to `1`, `false` to `0`
- For `null` -> `0` (because `null` is falsy)
- For `undefined` -> `NaN`
- For numbers: pass-through
- For strings:

  - only numeric [0-9] chars, starts with numeric or `+` or `-` -> number (integer)
  - same, but contains floating-point -> number (floating-point)
  - contains hexadecimal -> number (integer)
  - empty string -> `0`
  - all other cases -> `NaN`
- For objects, their `valueOf()` method is called. If result is `NaN`, then `toString()` method is called. Under the hood, the object is converted to primitive and that primitive is converted to number.
- For symbols and BigInts -> `TypeError` is thrown

**Note on number format**

As the question still attracts answers and comments that are concerned with formatting (as validly stated by the accepted answer), it should be stated that:

> As applied to programming, there is a strict meaning of **"number format"**:
> **representation of the numeric value**
>
> **"conversion"** also has a strict meaning as **type conversion** (see [standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-type-conversion))

ECMAScript implements *double-precision 64-bit format* and that's the only "format" it has. The question asks about *converting a String to number format*, therefore answers are expected to provide info on:

> How to convert String to Number given the value represents a number in e-notation

**References**

1. `ToNumber` [abstract operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) in ECMAScript standard
2. One of the best reads I had on this topic and many others: Matt Frisbie's "Professional Javascript for Web Developers".
3. Type coercion explained ([blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/))

Answer (score 1):

For integers you can use BigInt. Not very precise for really big numbers, but works perfectly and I found it the most concise and easy to remember options:

```
BigInt(1e18).toString() => '1000000000000000000'
BigInt(1e36).toString() => '1000000000000000042420637374017961984'

BigInt(Math.round(4.874915326E7)).toString() => '48749153'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MathJs library worked best for me, tried a lot of these answers and none of them worked properly under certain circumstances. This worked perfectly. More at https://mathjs.org/

Solution, add MathJS and then call it like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjs@8.0.1/lib/browser/math.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    function toPlainString(num) {
        return math.format(num,  {notation: 'fixed'});
    }
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not a huge fan of the idea of importing an entire library for a solution that can be achieved with one line of native code. This is how we write big, inefficient applications and should be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

For me the **easy/safest** way is the following:

```
export function stringifyNumber(num: number) {
    const [integer, decimals] = num.toString().split(".");
    if (decimals) {
        return BigInt(integer).toString() + "." + BigInt(decimals).toString();
    }
    return BigInt(integer).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertScientificToDecimal(number) {
  const decimalPlaces = -Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number)));
  return Number(number.toFixed(decimalPlaces));
}

const numberInScientificNotation = 3.5209577676952493e-10;
const decimalNumber = convertScientificToDecimal(numberInScientificNotation);

console.log(decimalNumber); // 0.0000000004
```