# How can I create the mathematical number 1e6 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

How do I create the number 1e6 with JavaScript?

```
var veryLargeNumber = //1e6
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I should've popped this into the console before posting it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are some different ways:

```
var veryLargeNumber = 1e6;

var veryLargeNumber = 1.0e+06;

var veryLargeNumber = 1000000;

var veryLargeNumber = 0xf4240;

var veryLargeNumber = 03641100;

var veryLargeNumber = Math.pow(10, 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is written the way you wrote it: `var notVeryLargeNumber = 1e6`.

Answer (score 1):

Like you wrote above:

```
var veryLargeNumber = 1e6;//Equals to 1*10^6
```

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine for me

```
var veryLargeNumber = 1e6;
console.log( veryLargeNumber );
```

outputs:

> 1000000

For more information about really "large" numbers within JavaScript, have a look at this question:

[What is JavaScript's Max Int? What's the highest Integer value a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Answer (score 1):

For the curious, I went on a little learning safari...

> Although the E stands for exponent, the notation is usually referred to as (scientific) E notation or (scientific) e notation

...

> Because superscripted exponents like 10^7 cannot always be conveniently displayed, the letter E or e is often used to represent "times ten raised to the power of" (which would be written as "× 10n") and is followed by the value of the exponent; in other words, for any two real numbers m and n, the usage of "mEn" would indicate a value of m × 10n.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

---

> Use exponential notation if number starts with “0.” followed by more than five zeros. Example:

```
> 0.0000003
3e-7
```

http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/displaying-numbers.html

---

Also: [How to convert a String containing Scientific Notation to correct Javascript number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943997/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-scientific-notation-to-correct-javascript-num)

```
Number("4.874915326E7") //returns 48749153.26
```