# How to convert big negative scientific notation number into decimal notation string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

converter_scientific_notation_to_decimal_notation('1.34E-15') or converter_scientific_notation_to_decimal_notation(1.34E-15)

=> '0.00000000000000134'

converter_scientific_notation_to_decimal_notation('2.54E-20') or
converter_scientific_notation_to_decimal_notation(2.54E-20)

=> '0.000000000000000000254'

Does such function exist in Javascript?

parseFloat is not good for big negative scientific number.

```
parseFloat('1.34E-5') => 0.0000134
parseFloat('1.34E-15') => 1.34e-15
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works for any positive or negative **number** with the  exponential 'E', positive or negative. (You can convert a numerical string to a number by prefixing '+', or make it a string method, or a method of any object, and call the string or number.)

```
Number.prototype.noExponents= function(){
    var data= String(this).split(/[eE]/);
    if(data.length== 1) return data[0]; 

    var  z= '', sign= this<0? '-':'',
    str= data[0].replace('.', ''),
    mag= Number(data[1])+ 1;

    if(mag<0){
        z= sign + '0.';
        while(mag++) z += '0';
        return z + str.replace(/^\-/,'');
    }
    mag -= str.length;  
    while(mag--) z += '0';
    return str + z;
}

var n=2.54E-20;
n.noExponents();
```

returned value:

```
"0.0000000000000000000254"
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you! Too bad, Javascript does not have built-in function for this. I still don't understand why parseFloat works differently with big negative scientific notation number than with modest negative scientific notation number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use toFixed: `(1.34E-15).toFixed(18)`  returns `0.000000000000001340`

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for the second example: `(2.54e-20).toFixed(20)` rounds instead.

Comment: Also, where the exponent is greater than 20, [*toFixed*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) will throw a range error exceptoin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [from-exponential](https://github.com/shrpne/from-exponential) module. It is lightweight and fully tested.

It accepts strings and numbers so it will not lose precision during conversion.

```
import fromExponential from 'from-exponential';

fromExponential('1.12345678901234567890e-10'); 
// '0.00000000011234567890123456789'
```