# How to round fractional value in JavaScript properly

Tags: javascript

How to round the factorial value in java scripts if we have below value

```
7.156945704626378 e +118
```

I want 7.16 only
please let me know if we have any solution?

Comment: If you exclude the exponent value, the representation value might change

Comment: Do you want `7.16`, or `7.16e+118`?

Comment: `7.156945704626378e118` = `715694570462637800000000000000...000.00`. What exactly do you mean by "I want _7.16_"?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a String variable:

```
var x = "7.156945704626378e+118";
```

Then use a regular expresion which checks for the part before e and parse it back to float:

```
var y = parseFloat(x.match(/\d+[.][0-9]+/)[0]);
```

And round to 2 decimal points by:

```
var z = y.toFixed(2);
```

If you still want your e118 just multiply z with 1e118 then.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPyrR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
((Number(7.156945704626378e+118))/1.0e+118).toFixed(2);
```

try this

you can refer links

[Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

and

[How to convert a String containing Scientific Notation to correct Javascript number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943997/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-scientific-notation-to-correct-javascript-num)

Comment: `7.156945704626378e+118` is already a number, why do you need to convert it to a number explicitly? And if you do, you have to use `Number()`.

Comment: Actully its a scirntific number.. to convert it to actual number we need to use `number` here

Comment: It's still `Number`, capital `N`, and don't think this would work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var number=7.1569;
number*=100;
var new_number = Math.round(number);
new_number/=100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this approach is correct but this give what user want in question.

```
Number((+num.toString().replace(/e.*/, '')).toFixed(2))
```

**DEMO**

```
var num = 7.156945704626378e+118;
console.log(Number((+num.toString().replace(/e.*/, '')).toFixed(2)));

# 7.16
```

**Note**:
This assumes that exponent is not significant and `mantissa` is **what all required for rounding off**.