# Convert string with exponential number to floating

Tags: node.js, string, parsing, exponential

I'm working on a NodeJs script that handles strings with exponential values.

Something like this:

> 1.070000000000000e+003

Which is the best way to convert (or parse) this string and obtain a floating value?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943997/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-scientific-notation-to-correct-javascript-num)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT thanks! I solved with Number

Answer (score 0):

You may convert by using `parseFloat` or `Number`

If you prefer to parse, maybe the best way is by a regular expression:

```
/-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638565/parsing-scientific-notation-sensibly) and convert the single capturing group.