# js add comma at Sextillion values

Tags: javascript

I use one small code js to add comma to value:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

I have problem when try to add comma to big values like sextillion values.
Eg.

```
addCommas(1000000) //return correct "1,000,000"
```

but if use big values like this

```
addCommas(50949024266983356472874) // return wrong "5.094902426698335e+22"
```

What or where I do wrong?

Comment: I found this with seems kind of relevant but might not be very helpful: [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number is stored in a string the following function will achieve what you are asking for.

```
function addCommas( txtNum ) {
    var parts = txtNum.split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].reverse().replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1,").reverse();
    return parts.join(".");
}   

String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("");
}

addCommas( "-50000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000" );
// => -50,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.0000
```

Comment: This works only if the input is a string, not a number, which isn't what appear in the question.

Comment: @dystroy You are correct. Just thought I would add just in case but happy to delete if it turns out that it is irrelevant :)

Comment: That is what i need. I search response for my problem here but I did not find.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

<s>Your input might already be a float. Numbers larger than 2^32 tend to be like this.</s> Make sure your input is a string and your function will run fine.

JavaScript doesn't have `int` and `float` types. Instead it just has a `Number` type and it will decide on it's own when to use which.

Comment: No, `50949024266983356472874` is represented in scientific notation when converted to a string.

Comment: E.g. call it as `addCommas('50949024266983356472874');`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
nStr += '';
```

You're asking javascript to first convert your number to a string. That's when it decides to write it as `"5.094902426698335e+22"`. The problem isn't in the rest of your algorithm.

The conversion is described [here in ecmascript](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.8)