# Printing floating point values with decimals and not with e-notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When i print a floating point like `0.0000001` in JavaScript it gives me

```
 1e-7
```

how can i avoid that and instead print it "normally" ?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html I believe this page will help you

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
var x = 0.00000001;
var toPrint = x.toFixed(7);
```

This sets `toPrint` to a string representation of `x` with 7 digits to the right of the decimal point. To use this, you need to know how many digits of precision you need. You will also need to trim off any trailing 0 digits if you don't want them (say, if `x` was 0.04).

Comment: find out precision and trim trailing zeroes?

Comment: @clamp Precision is probably something you know based on the context of the number.

Comment: @clamp - You cannot find the precision. The problem is that floating point values are not exact (e.g., 0.1 does not have a terminating binary expansion). You simply need to pick a precision that fits your needs. As far as trailing zeroes goes, that's pretty easy: `toPrint.replace(/(\..*?)0+$/, '$1')` will chop off trailing zeroes that follow a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

```
function noExponent(n){
    var data= String(n).split(/[eE]/);
    if(data.length== 1) return data[0]; 

    var  z= '', sign= +n<0? '-':'',
    str= data[0].replace('.', ''),
    mag= Number(data[1])+ 1;

    if(mag<0){
        z= sign + '0.';
        while(mag++) z += '0';
        return z + str.replace(/^\-/,'');
    }
    mag -= str.length;  
    while(mag--) z += '0';
    return str + z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks kennebec.
Actually your solution above is the only one that works for preventing a number like "0.0000001" (1e-7) to be displayed with scientific notation, since doing: "0.0000001".toFixed(7)
Will still display: 1e-7 At least in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple solution that appears to be working.

```
var rx = /^([\d.]+?)e-(\d+)$/;

var floatToString = function(flt) {
  var details, num, cnt, fStr = flt.toString();
  if (rx.test(fStr)) {
    details = rx.exec(fStr);
    num = details[1];
    cnt = parseInt(details[2], 10);
    cnt += (num.replace(/\./g, "").length - 1); // Adjust for longer numbers
    return flt.toFixed(cnt);
  }
  return fStr;
};

floatToString(0.0000001); // returns "0.0000001"
```

**EDIT** Updated it to use the `toFixed` (didn't think about it).

**EDIT 2** Updated it so it will display numbers `0.0000000123` properly instead of chopping off and showing `"0.00000001"`.

Comment: You'll want `\d+` to allow for numbers in which the exponent has more than 1 digit.

Comment: @AaronDufour Good catch, left that off.