# How to format (really) big numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, formatting, precision, arbitrary-precision

I want something like the library [JavaScript BigNum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) and [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) working together.

In Numeral.js, I can use strings like this:

```
var number = numeral('1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000011111111100');
```

but the result of `number.format();` is really disappointing:

```
"1.11e+84"
```

Any way to format a (really) big number nicely?

**EDIT:** I don't want just avoid scientific notation, it was a wrong assumption. I want to "nicely" format, as I want, for example:

```
var number = numeral(1000);
numeral.defaultFormat('$0,0.00');

number.format();
// '$1,000.00'
```

Well, if the number is big:

```
var number = numeral('100000000000000000000000000');
"$9.999999999999999e+25"
```

This is a mess. I know JavaScript can't handle big numbers, but my question is **exactly** because that! I would like a library or a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Javascript itself does not handle really big numbers like you show with appropriate precision.  So you have two choices: 1) keep it as a string and manipulate it only as a string or 2) get a third party library that handles really big numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: @ochi: No, as that doesn't deal with bignums but only the builtin `number` type

Comment: It is not duplicate. My question is about number formatting, like what if I want to show as money? Like USD 100,000,000.00 (in English US) or R$ 23,00 (in Portuguese BR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supporting only [recent browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Browser_compatibility), I think it might be enough for you to just use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Although you it lose precision on big numbers, it will help you show big numbers and currencies pretty easily:

```js
var number = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// → 1.234.567.890.123.460.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000,00 €

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// → ￥1,234,567,890,123,460,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format, String.prototype.slice(), String.prototype.concat()

```
var number = 2.9364136545300044e+24;
var n = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number);
var res = n.slice(0, 9).concat(".").concat(n.slice(10, 12));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think you could improve this answer by helping the readers see what that console.log would show. Besides, if I were you I would also explain why you used slice and concat in here. By the way, I don't think losing those digits in big numbers is really what the OP was looking for, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: This will lose precision in the later digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers like '1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000011111111100' to be handled and printed without precision lost you can:

1. Store this number as a string and never convert into number. The disadvantage is clear here: you will be not able perform arithmetic operations with numbers in string representation.
2. You can use one of big numbers library, e.g. big-numbers (https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-numbers). This will allow you to perform calculations and do not lost precision.

Example code:

```
var bn = new BugNumbers();
var longNumber = bn.of('1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000011111111100');

var longNumberPlusOne = longNumber.add(1);

// Should pring1110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000011111111101
console.log(bn.format(longNumberPlusOne));
```

Check documentation for details:
http://www.bignumbers.tech