# JavaScript returns odd number

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

I'm trying to make a simple script which updates a number based on input field.

Some of the calculations are based on very small numbers, and which makes JavaScript return odd numbers like: 7e-8.

How can I fix this?, I've tried searching google, but haven't found anything useful, like `.toFixed()`, `.toPrecision()` and such.

Another problem as well, is how can I limit the returned number to only 8 digits after the dot? Here as well I've tried to do `.toFixed(8)`, but from what I've seen on Google, it's rounding in some cases, which isn't good in my case.

Btw: the number 0.0000007 is pulled from database with PHP, so its not always that number. but its always with 8 digits after the dot.

```js
$("input[name='test']").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val() * 0.0000007;
  $("p").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" value="1">
<p></p>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript) may give you some direction.

Comment: I'm sorry, but doesn't help me much, can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution

had to place the .toFixed() the right place

```js
$("input[name='test']").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val() * 0.0000007;
  $("p").text(value.toFixed(8));
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" value="1">
<p></p>
```