# Display whole number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method which converts an IPv6 address to its decimal value.

At the moment my result is:

```
4.254076641128259e+37
```

But I need this:

```
42540766411282592857539836924043198464
```

My code:

```
var ip = '2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0';
var address = new v6.Address(ip);
var bin = address.binaryZeroPad();
var dec = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
    dec = dec + parseInt(bin[i]) * Math.pow(2, bin.length - 1 - i);
}
console.log(dec);
```

Im using the ip-address lib to convert IPv6 first to binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: You cannot represent an unsigned 128 bit number as a JavaScript number. JavaScript Number only allows storage of integers up to 2^53. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/898289. I'm just working on alternative solution....

Comment: Also note, this is not a duplicate, the answer linked does not deal with  large numbers.

Comment: is it maybe possible to add each section to a string?

Comment: You could use [BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)

Comment: @ Bali Balo
BigInteger.js readme says:
Note that Javascript numbers larger than 9007199254740992 and smaller than -9007199254740992 are not precisely represented numbers and will not produce exact results. If you are dealing with numbers outside that range, it is better to pass in strings.

Comment: No way, values in javascript has only 52 bits of precision. The only solution is a bignum method

Answer (score 2):

You cannot represent an unsigned 128 bit number as a JavaScript Number without losing precision. JavaScript Number only allows storage of integers up to 2^53. See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/898289)

See the 08d3 group has been lost...

```
var dec = 42540766411282592857539836924043198464;
console.log(dec.toString(16))
// ==> 20010db8000000000000000000000000
```

An alternative is to use another library to simulate arbitrary large integers, like [BigInteger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) ([WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) license).

Example with corresponding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamish/mrx3880p/)

```
var ip = '2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0';

// simulate your address.binaryZeroPad(); method
var parts = [];
ip.split(":").forEach(function(it) {
    var bin = parseInt(it, 16).toString(2);
    while (bin.length < 16) {
        bin = "0" + bin;
    }
    parts.push(bin);
})
var bin = parts.join("");

// Use BigInteger library
var dec = bigInt(bin, 2).toString();
console.log(dec);
```

**Output**

```
42540766411282592857539836924043198464
```

Comment: when i try to convert this i get a wrong value: 2a01:0ad0:0022::0

Comment: My IP6 conversion does not deal with :: notation. I only included it because I did not have access to whatever code provides  new v6.Address(ip).... Out of interest what library is that? I couldn't find it on google....