# Dynamic number.toFixed() function

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript number.toFixed() function.

My problem is I have to explicitly mention number of fractional length like below:

if number is 1e11 then I have to specifiy it as

```
number.toFixed(2)
```

or if number is 1e1 then :

```
 number.toFixed(1)
```

or if its 1e0 then

```
number.toFixed(0)
```

I want to do it dynamically based on whether fractions present or not. and irrespective of fractional length.

I dont want to pass parameter of fixed fractional length. js should dynamically understand fractional length of it. Is there similar provision in JS? or is there any similar function in java script where I need not to explicitly pass parameter of fixed length?

Comment: You've stated a problem, but not asked a specific question

Comment: Isn't that the exact point of the toFixed-function? What are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: actually I dont want to pass parameter of fixed fractional length. js should dynamically  understand fractional length of it

Comment: "Understand" as in "guess the programmers intent"? Yeah, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Edited question to add more clearification

Comment: @Orion youve not really clarified anything. When you say "dynamically understand" what *rules* do you want to put in place? What is the desired output for a given input?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `number.toString()`? If the intention is to just get a string representation of your number, that might do what you want.

Comment: @Orion are you sure that the **1e0.11** will accept as number.? just try this

Comment: @Jamiec - I simply want to avoid passing parameter to number.toFIxed function and then I want out put as fixed value of given number and that should also with exact precision.  I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara - yeah it will surely get cast as number as it is scientific notation.

Comment: @Orion i think it should be like  123e5;      // 12300000  z = 123e-5 //0.00123; i have never seen like 1e0.11 it shows **Unexpected number** just try out using console

Comment: @Orion [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Floating-point_literals) disagrees with you: "The exponent part is an "e" or "E" followed by **an integer**" 0.11 is not an integer, so 1e0.11 isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, OP has made a simple mistake - those numbers must surely be `1e0`, `1e1` and `1e11`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @Jamiec - Sorry I made mistake in representation of scientific number. You are correct.

Comment: @Orion - protip: Thats the point at which you go back and edit your question (ive done it for you!). See the answer I linked above, its the answer to your question too I think.

Answer (score -1):

```
var temp = number.split('.');
if (typeof temp[1] !== 'undefined') {
  console.log(temp[1].length); // here you got it
} else {
 // 0
}
```

Comment: kindly comment after voting negative

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but how does this solve their issue?

Comment: as far as i understand he needs the parameter inside toFixed to be calculated dynamically.