# Have max. 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, math, tofixed

With `.toFixed(2)` I always get 2 decimals, even if the number is 2.00

Can I get "2" instead?

Example:

- 2.00 => 2
- 2.05 => 2.05
- 2.053435 => 2.05
- 2.057435 => 2.06

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: but that also suggets I use toFixed(2) which doesn't work like I want

Comment: So use the script from the most voted answer? Here's [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/af3qg9bc/)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```js
function toFixedIfNecessary( value, dp ){
  return +parseFloat(value).toFixed( dp );
}

console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 1.999, 2 ));    // 2
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2, 2 ));        // 2
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.1, 2 ));      // 2.1
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.05, 2 ));     // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.05342, 2 ));  // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.04999, 2 ));  // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.04499, 2 ));  // 2.04
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.053435, 2 )); // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.057435, 2 )); // 2.06
```

Comment: What sworcery is this? Can someone explain why +parseFloat has this behaviour?

Comment: @homebrand the + converts the string output of toFixed back to a float. Try `+"2.00"` in the console

Comment: This use case scenario is not covered:
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary(0.000000032, 10 ));    // 3.2e-8

Comment: This will convert `66.666` to `66.67`.

Comment: @wintercounter Of course, `66.666` rounds to `66.67` to 2 decimal places. If you were expecting `66.66` then that is truncating the number and not rounding and is an entirely different question.

Comment: OP didn't ask to round it.

Comment: @wintercounter Implicitly, yes, they did as they asked for it to (at most) 2 decimal places which the common definition means that if there is more than 2 decimal places then it should be rounded to 2 decimal places. If you want a non-standard meaning of the term "to 2 d.p." then you need to specify that you not rounding and instead want to truncate, floor, ceiling, round half-up, etc.

Comment: @GeraldoB.Landre That is a display/formatting problem and not a rounding problem. `toFixedIfNecessary(value, 10 )` returns a number with at most 10 decimal places and correctly rounded; if your number is small then JavaScript's default method of displaying it is to use scientific notation and your issue is that you want to format the number differently not that it is rounded incorrectly. For formatting, look at some of the later answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1685680/1509264) such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36028587/1509264) (and my comment on it).

Comment: I think it's worth making it explicit in the answer that in cases like this, the function may not behave as expected. `toFixed`'s definition says it "formats a number using fixed-point notation." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Therefore, the reader is possibly expecting the method to be returning a string with the format requested in the question.

If it's not possible to accomplish what is being asked for all cases, then, that is an important part of the answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.round()`:

```js
var number = 2.005;
var number2 = 2.558934;
var number3 = 1.005;

function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}

console.log(round(number, 2)) // > 2.01
console.log(round(number2, 2)) // > 2.56
console.log(round(number3, 2)) // > 1.01
```

Comment: `Math.round( 1.005 * 100 ) / 100` returns `1`

Comment: And it should return 1, because we want maximum 2 decimal places, but if you input 1.05 it will return 1.05, or if we input 1.051264 it will return 1.05

Comment: @NevenIgnjic `1.005` to 2dp is `1.01` not `1`

Comment: It depends, I came across two types of rounding when the input is at the half between to values it needs to snap.
1. Snap to higher or lower value
2. Snap to closest even or odd number

So it all depends what kind of software is calculating this, but to the OP these things don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
function toFixedIfNecessary(value, dp){
  return +value.toFixed(dp);
}

console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 1.999, 2 ));    // 2
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2, 2 ));        // 2
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.1, 2 ));      // 2.1
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.05, 2 ));     // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.05342, 2 ));  // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.04999, 2 ));  // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.04499, 2 ));  // 2.04
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.053435, 2 )); // 2.05
console.log( toFixedIfNecessary( 2.057435, 2 )); // 2.06
```

This is a modification of the answer by @MTO

`parseFloat()` is not necessary