# Given the string representations of two integers, return the string representation of the sum of those integers

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
sumStrings('1','2') // => '3'
C# sumStrings("1","2") // => "3"
```

My code:

```
function sumStrings(a,b) { 
a = Number(a);
b = Number(b); 
var total = a + b ;
return total.toString();
}
```

When I try the above code with the following, it has a problem.

```
sumStrings('712569312664357328695151392', '8100824045303269669937');
```

I get :

```
7.125774134884027e+26
```

Instead of:

```
712577413488402631964821329
```

Help please!

Comment: Your problem is the number precision.  Check out this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is being returned to you in floating point because it is greater than the maximum integer value.

The max int value in javascript I believe is 9007199254740991.

You can check the limits by viewing: `alert([ Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE ]);`

Edit: If you need big integer math without loss of precision, you need a biginteger library similar to this: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Comment: This is true but not an answer to the question.

Comment: I added an edit, I guess I wasn't clear on the question. If he wants the big numbers, he needs a big Number library to do the math.