# What is number and how to convert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have custom calculator with js, everything was normal until i found `1.2101997764095421e-12` sometimes `X.XXe-13`, `X.XXe-14`

What is this ? How to convert it ?

Update : 
I have knowledge in excel for this calculator, the result for `1.2101997764095421e-12` should be a `14,78`

Comment: convert it to what?

Comment: @Cyril I have knowledge in excel for this calculator, the result for `1.2101997764095421e-12` should be a `14,78`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: what kind of math is that?

Comment: Maybe you learn how to use your javascript calculator first. Cannot imagine how numbers so different in size and amount could be result of same equation. What is the calculation for which these are the results?

Answer (score 0):

Those are really long floating point number, and the e-12 represents that there are 12 decimals. To convert it to your desired format you can do this:

```
var converted = Math.round(number * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing specific to javascript but a common mathematical notation meaning the following:

```
1e-1 = 0.1
1e-2 = 0.01
```

x.xxe-13 points to a number having 13 decimals after 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a representation of [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  You can translate the eN to mean x10^N.  When a Float number gets to large or small the string representation number will look that way.

```
1.12345e5 = 1.12345x10^5 = 112345
1.12345e-5 = 1.12345x10^-5 = .0000112345
```