# Any way to get JavaScript numbers without Euler's number

Tags: javascript, math, eulers-number

I try to get

`Math.pow(2,1000);`

The result is " 1.2676506002282294e+30 "

I need the number without Euler's number "e+30"

Comment: It's not Euler's numbers... that's 2.718 lol

Comment: Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: That's called _exponential notation_. Take a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript), it addresses the same problem =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), not Euler's number.

If you want to show the number without the `e+NN` part:

- convert it to a string
- parse the `e+NN` part
- shift the decimal place the appropriate number of digits
- return the output as a string

<sub>be aware that doing so will lead to inaccurate values for some calculations due to how floating point arithmetic works.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

With very large numbers, JavaScript displays them in scientific notation. This is because it is very expensive and unreadable to list them.

For your example, it basically means

```
1.2676506002282294 * 10 ^ 30
```

You take the number and then multiply it by 10 to the 30th power.

> Calculators often use "E" or "e" like this: 1.8004E+94
>
> 6E+5 is the same as 6 × 10^5

To get it without this notation, simply use smaller numbers as the exponent.

Example: `Math.pow(2,10)`

Mathisfun provides an excellent article on scientific notation. Check it out here

https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/scientific-notation.html

Euler's number is a constant that is the base of a natural number. It's an irrational number, meaning its digits go on forever. The first couple digits are `2.7182818284`