# How to get precise integer result for arithmetic operations of huge numbers in JS?

Tags: javascript

How to get precise integer result for **multiplication** and **division** operations of huge numbers in JS?

Let's say we have:

```
var a = 75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235342;
var b = 34986098309687982743378379458582778387652482;
```

Multiplying these numbers gives me a number in scientific "e" notation. How to display the whole precise integer result number?

I've tried using this library
https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Readme says:

> Note that Javascript numbers larger than **9007199254740992** and
>   smaller than **-9007199254740992** are not precisely represented
>   numbers and will not produce exact results. If you are dealing with
>   numbers outside that range, it is better to pass in strings.

But how do you do math with strings?

Comment: why would you need such a precise number?

Answer (score 3):

Use bigInt, as you hinted, you need to use strings instead of numbers to represent them correctly.

```
bigInt("75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235342").multiply("34986098309687982743378379458582778387652482");
```

Comment: Thanks. But it returns an array, could you also advise how to make it a string?  `.join("")` throws an error `result.join is not a function` if I try to join the variable `var result` containing that operation

Comment: That becomes another question entirely... "How to make BigInteger work with floating numbers?" And I am sorry, but I cannot answer this.

Comment: Well, yeah, I can see the same thing in Python. Not sure why. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Python is better with Mathematics than javascript... At least that's why researchers say they use that instead... But I couldn't say.

Answer (score -1):

I think this question is duplicate of [how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

This function taken from above link.

```
function toFixed(x) {
 if (Math.abs(x) < 1.0) {
 var e = parseInt(x.toString().split('e-')[1]);
 if (e) {
    x *= Math.pow(10,e-1);
    x = '0.' + (new Array(e)).join('0') + x.toString().substring(2);
  }
} else {
var e = parseInt(x.toString().split('+')[1]);
if (e > 20) {
    e -= 20;
    x /= Math.pow(10,e);
    x += (new Array(e+1)).join('0');
 }
}
 return x;
}

 alert(toFixed(a*b));
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of precision at all.