# How do I display very small numbers in my messenger bot without E notation?

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

[image]

I have a bot that needs to display very small conversions in crypto. Currently, when the number is small, the output shows in scientific notation with E. I don't want this notation, how can I format this to display like a normal number

Thanks for your answers in advance. Coded in Node.js

Comment: Which language are u using? C# or Node?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toFixed()` on your number to show the number with the desired precision.

```
number.toFixed(precision)
```

Here is an example:

```
let number = 0.000000635345

number.toFixed(5)    // 0.00000
number.toFixed(6)    // 0.000001
number.toFixed(7)    // 0.0000006
number.toFixed(8)    // 0.00000064
```

You can use this in in conjunction with a RegExp to remove the trailing zeros:

```
let number = 0.0000005
number.toFixed(10)                          // 0.0000005000

number.toFixed(10).replace(/\.?0+$/,"")     // 0.0000005
```