# AngularJs ng-model gets me 5e+21 when I input a number with lots of zeroes

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-model

I'm a bit confused here..

I'm trying to create a field with number and binding it into ng-model, but when I  input this value

```
10000000000000000000000
```

It gets me `1e+22` on the model result, how can I make it as number not this string when I input lot of 0 behind.

Hopefully somebody here giving me 10000000000000000000000 then it should returns 10000000000000000000000 on the ng-model.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaxoXJ

Thank you

Comment: You can change `type='number'` to `type='text'` and apply mask on this input or preserve input value on `ng-change`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it as number not this string when I input lot of 0 behind.

It's not a string, it's a number displayed using the scientific notation. Javascript uses this notation for big numbers. For example, in JS, this king of statement is valid :

```
var i = 1e+22;
```

Instead of using `{{test}}` to display your value, call a function to format the number correctly (the result will be a string and not an number).

[This post explains how to print a number wihout using the scientific notation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGbOrz)