# Pitfalls with using scientific notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, scientific-notation

This question is **not** seeking developer code formatting opinions. Personally, I prefer to use scientific notation in my JS code when I can because I believe it is more readable. For me, `6e8` is more readable than `600000000`. That being said, I am solely looking for potential risks and disadvantages specifying numbers in scientific notation in JS. I don't see it often in the wild and was wondering if there is technical reasoning for that or if it simply because of developer's druthers.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you wondering whether every environment supports this notation? Or whether you will get the value you are specifying?

Comment: @FelixKling, good point. I was thinking more along the lines of preserving the original value being specified. I'm open to any issues that might come up when using scientific notation in my JS, though.

Comment: @EvanWieland, not sure about of risks, but JS does allows sceintific notation. Wikipedia `In most popular programming languages, 6.022E23 (or 6.022e23) is equivalent to 6.022×1023, and 1.6×10−35 would be written 1.6E-35 (e.g. Ada, Analytica, C/C++, FORTRAN (since FORTRAN II as of 1958), MATLAB, Scilab, Perl, Java,[4] Python, Lua, JavaScript, and others).`

Comment: This link probably helps better to understand, why scientific notation cannot be processed as is without conversion. I do not think there is any risk or disadvantages. As long as the programming language supports it is all good. https://blog.penjee.com/binary-numbers-floating-point-conversion/

Comment: I have to remember using this notation for big numbers to avoid counting zeroes with the mouse pointer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see scientific notation *"often in the wild"* because the only numbers that actually get typed in JS tend to be constants:

- Code-centric constants (such as enums and levels) tend to be small.
- Physical/mathematical constants (such as π or e) tend to be highly specific.

Neither of these benefit from scientific notation too much.

I have seen [Plank's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) 'in the wild' as:

```js
const h = 6.62607004e-34;
console.log('Plank', h);
```

The other place it often makes sense is time limits, for instance the number of ms in a day as `864e5`. For instance:

```js
function addDaysToDate(date, days) {
  if (days === 0)
    return date;
  date.setTime(864e5 * days + date.valueOf());
  return date;
}

const now = new Date();
const thisTimeTomorrow = addDaysToDate(now, 1);
console.log('This time tomorrow', thisTimeTomorrow);
```

I don't think there's any technical reason not to use this notation, it's more that developers avoid hard coding numbers at all.

I don't think there are any risks. You may have to be careful with numbers in strings, but if you're doing that then this syntax is a far smaller issue than, say, number localisation (for instance a DE user entering `"20.000,00"`, expecting `2e4`, but getting `2e6` thanks to invariant number formatting swapping the thousand and decimal separators).

I'd add that JS will output that syntax by default anyway for small numbers, but avoids for large numbers up to a point (which varies by browser):

```js
console.log('Very small', 1234 / 100000000000)
console.log('Large, but still full in some browsers', 1e17 * 1234)
console.log('Large, scientific', 1e35 * 1234)
```

Comment: Timeouts such as `60e3`ms often are constants in a range that would seem reasonable for scientific notation.

Comment: @Bergi ah, very good point, and I have seen that too! I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't understand the sample of the DE user (I suppose it means German user). It wouldn't be `2e4` (20000) with German decimal comma and `2e1` (20) with English decimal point?

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez It depends on the localised parser - either way it doesn't come out right. Yeah it means user with German locality; a system I once worked on found a bug that effectively multiplied thousands of German input salaries by 100 (thanks to e4 becoming e6) - that was fun to fix :-| My point is: if you're passing round numbers as strings i18n is a _much_ bigger issue than scientific notation - the latter is far more consistently parsed - I'd rather have `"2e4"` than `"20,000.00"` or `"20.000,00"` any day.

Comment: I agree, I was asking only for clarification on e-notation, living in a country that uses the same decimal marks than Germany means that I'm pretty aware of that issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

From O. R. Mapper in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1685680/1456253) question:

> Human users are not the only ones who want to read numbers. It seems
>   D3 will throw an exception when encountering a translate
>   transformation that contains coordinates in scientific notation

In addition, if you want change the string representation, as opposed to just what the literal looks like in your source, you'll have to be careful with serialized/stored data.

Also, from experience, often times you can have large numbers whose significance is in their individual digits like an ID or phone number. In this case, reducing these numbers to scientific notation hurts readability.

Comment: I don’t see how this quote is relevant here. The question you linked to is about how JavaScript converts large numbers to strings. It’s not about *specifying* numbers in scientific notation (this question).

Comment: You're right, its only relevant if he does what I mentioned in my second sentence: `In addition, if you want change the string representation, as opposed to just what the literal looks like in your source...` Should have put that first.

Comment: But that happens regardless of using scientific notation. It happens to all numbers larger than a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

> [E-notation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Javascript_Tutorial/Data_Type/How_to_write_Scientific_notation_literal_in_Javascript.htm) indicates a number that should be multiplied by 10 raised
>   to a given power.

is not scientific exponential notation . One pitfall is that [`e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) *"times ten raised to the power of"* in JavaScript is not [`The number e`](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html) the base of the natural logarithm, represented at browser as `Math.E`. For individuals familiar with the mathematical constant [*`e`*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html), JavaScript `e` has an entirely different meaning. `6 * Math.pow(10, 8)` returns expected result and does not include use of the JavaScript artifact `e`.

> Although the E stands for exponent, the notation is usually referred
>   to as (scientific) E-notation rather than (scientific) exponential
>   notation. The use of E-notation facilitates data entry and readability
>   in textual communication since it minimizes keystrokes, avoids reduced
>   font sizes and provides a simpler and more concise display, but it is
>   not encouraged in publications. [Submission Guidelines for Authors:
>   HPS 2010 Midyear
>   Proceedings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#cite_note-3)