# How to add large sums without returning an exponential in javascript

Tags: javascript, exponential

/* 
how can i return the full value not exponential?
*/

```js
x = 11111111111111111111111112;
y = 23233333333333333333333333;
console.log(x+y);

//how can i return the full value not exponential?
```

Comment: Is it just for reading purposes? If so, you can use `(x+y).toLocaleString()` to have a readable number, but the formatting will depend on your locale (it will probably add thousands separators).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no greater than 253 are representable in the `Number` type (the integer 0 has two representations, +0 and −0). That means the valid range for `Number` is **+/- 9007199254740991**.

Anything bigger than that range are handled as floating point, in which case it is really difficult to avoid exponent.

```js
let x = 11111111111111111111111112;
let y = 23233333333333333333333333;
console.log(parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y))
console.log(x+y);
```

If you want to handle big integers, you can take the help of some library:
[BigInteger](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)