# long number issues in google developer tool

Tags: javascript

when I try to convert a long number to a string and an array by using google dev tool, I got a problem.

```
let m=123000000000000000000000000000000
//1.23e+32
m=m+'good'
//"1.23e+32good"
// instead of "123000000000000000000000000000000good"
```

I plan to get the result of ["1","2","3","0",....."0"],but now I'm stuck.
anyone know how to solve this? 
Thanks.

---

**Intl.NumberFormat** is a good way, but when I try a long number:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {useGrouping: false}).format(73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934)
//"73167176531330600000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

ops. There is still an issue.

Comment: Use string instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string instead:

```js
//current result
var m = 123000000000000000000000000000000;
m = m + 'good';
console.log(m);

//desired result
var n = '123000000000000000000000000000000';
n = n + 'good';
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Intl.NumberFormat` API:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {useGrouping: false}).format(123000000000000000000000000000000)
```

returns a string:

```
"123000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: That's a good solution and deserve its place in [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberToDigitNumber(number) {
    let arrayOfNumber = number.toString().split('e+');
    let digitsOfNumber = arrayOfNumber[0].replace('.' , '');
    for(let i = 0; i < Number(arrayOfNumber[1]); i++) {
        digitsOfNumber += '0';
    }
    return digitsOfNumber;
}

let num = 123000000000000000000000000000000;
console.log(numberToDigitNumber(num) + ', instead of ' + num);
// -> 123000000000000000000000000000000 instead of 123e+32
```

Use this function, i created one for this problem. You can define a variable and assign its number value with this fuckion like this;

```
let myNumber = numberToDigitNumber(123000000000000);
```