# how to type just 0-9 in number type (exclude 'e')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux-form

I wonder how am I use `type=number` that can type just 0-9 without 'e' in **javascript**.

```
<Field 
    name="weight" 
    type="number" 
    component={TextField} 
    placeholder="" 
    label="Weight(%)"  
    width={250} />
```

Thank you

Comment: There no is field tag.

Comment: The question is most likely about how to avoid the *scientific notation* for an `input` field, it's just phrased poorly (likely because OP did not know the correct terminology for that `e` character). I believe an answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript), although it will most likely require using an input with type `text`, which will then require converting from the number to text (without scientific notation) and back.

Answer (score 0):

One can do it using JavaScript by incorporating `type="text"` instead of `number` and applying a conditional check on `keypress` event as below:

```html
<div>
  <h4>Allow Only Numbers </h4>
  <input type="text" name="onlyNumbers" id="numberField" />
</div>
<script>
  function allowNumbersOnly(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;
    if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) { // keyCode for '0' is 48 and for '9' it is 57
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('numberField').addEventListener('keypress', allowNumbersOnly);
</script>
```