# How to prevent large textfield numbers from getting converted into 1e notation -Javascript/EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textfield with input only and no max limit set on the size of the input. Now when I enter large numbers the number gets converted into `1e` notation.
ex:

[image]

I;m using EXTJs as my code base:
code:

```
$cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
        items: [
            this.section({
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        this.limit = new Ext.form.NumberField({
                            cls: "limit-number-field",
                            allowBlank: false,
                            allowNegative: false,
                            allowDecimals: false,
                            width: 150
                        })
                    ]
                }]
            })
        ]
    }, cfg));
```

also here are the logs of the numbers I have tried with `toFixed()`
[image]

and they all give me same o/p. not sure what im doing wrong here.

how to  prevent this from happening. I want the number to be there in the input field as is.

PS> I referred to [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript/1685917)
but this did not work for me.
any ideas?

Comment: What exactly did not work from that other question? Numbers aren't "converted" to scientific notation; it's just a display convention. Ultimately a JavaScript number *must* be converted to a string in order to be shown as the value of an `<input>` because `<input>` values are *always* strings.

Comment: Save and display user input as-is typed. Nothing will be converted.

Comment: @M1K1O: I did not get your comment. what do you mean?.

Comment: @user1234 you will treat user input as ordinary string. And then in your business logic convert it to number.

Comment: @Pointy: I mean that I tried: ```function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}``` and then ```console.log(financial('1.23e+5'));``` it gives me: 123000.00, but not the number that I originally entered. this causes conflicts when sending a payload to the server.

Comment: But `1.23e+5` is in fact `123000.00`.

Comment: @Pointy: updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Numbers that are that large after going to lose precision. Easiest way to deal with it is to restrict the input to 16 characters. Or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: I think this is really an ExtJS issue.

Comment: I think you are using numberfield of extjs. If you want to support larger numbers, use an Ext.form.TextField that only allows numbers to be entered (so the final value is a String and not a Number)

Comment: @Jaydeep: I could have used Ext.form.TextField({}), but I want to restrict decimals and negative numbers being entered into the field and I'm not sure if textfield provides that ability, I know NumberField does and hence used that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a textfield that allows the user to type a long string of digits without any formatting you could use a textfield with [maskRe](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-maskRe). This will allow the user to only type characters that match the regular expression in the mask.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Number',
    maskRe: /[0-9]/
}]
```

});

[see fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2stg)